# android random floats returning null

Tags: java, android

I am trying to generate 10 random locations on a surfaceView to draw 10 circles.
The code below assigns a random float value to x and y coordinates, but I keep receiving a nullpointer exception on the random value assignment and cant figure out why.

```
rndX = new float[10];
rndY = new float[10];

for(int i=0;i<rndX.length;i++)
{
   //get random x and y values
   rndX[i] = (float)generator.nextInt(surface.getWidth());
   rndY[i] = (float)generator.nextInt(surface.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Check with constant at surface methods

Comment: ok will I will try that

Comment: setting constants worked, does that mean the surface hasn't een created at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following works just fine.

```
    float[] rndX = new float[10];
    float[] rndY = new float[10];

    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;

    Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    for(int i=0;i<rndX.length;i++){
       rndX[i] = (float)generator.nextInt(width);
       rndY[i] = (float)generator.nextInt(height);
    }
```

What is causing your `NullPointerException` is probably that one of the `surface` or `generator` variables is not initialised.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with:

```
Random rand = new Random();

rndX = new float[10];
rndY = new float[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   //get random x and y values
   rndX[i] = rand.nextFloat();
   rndY[i] = rand.nextFloat();
}
```

Comment: Returns a pseudo-random uniformly distributed float in the half-open range [0.0, 1.0).